# .lower() method used whith input return boolean as False?

Tags: python, if-statement, nested

My ptoblem is with the lower() method, it doesn't convert the input in a lowercase and if i enter the city name with a lower case it shows it as False in debug. Can't figure out where is my mistake here :/

```
city = input().lower()
s = float(input("Volume sells: "))

result = 0
if city == "London":
    if 0 <= s <= 500:
        result = s * 0.05
    elif 500 < s <= 1000:
        result = s * 0.07
    elif 1000 < s <= 10000:
        result = s * 0.08
    elif s > 10000:
        result = s * 0.12

if city == "Kiev":
    if 0 <= s <= 500:
        result = s * 0.045
    elif 500 < s <= 1000:
        result = s * 0.075
    elif 1000 < s <= 10000:
        result = s * 0.1
    elif s > 10000:
        result = s * 0.13

elif city == "Sofia":
    if 0 <= s <= 500:
        result = s * 0.055
    elif 500 < s <= 1000:
        result = s * 0.08
    elif 1000 < s <= 10000:
        result = s * 0.12
    elif s > 10000:
        result = s * 0.145

else:
    result = 'Error'

if type(result) == str or s < 0:
    print(result)
else:
    print("{0:.2f}".format(result))
```

Comment: Aww why did you edit out the Bulgarian cities? It’s rare to stumble into those in places like this

Answer (score 0):

You're calling [`str.lower()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) on the input, but then comparing it to capitalized city names. Change your conditionals to use lowercase city names:

Replace:

```py
if city == "London":
...
if city == "Kiev":
...
elif city == "Sofia":
```

With:

```py
if city == "london":
...
if city == "kiev":
...
elif city == "sofia":
```

That should fix your immediate issue. Alternatively, you can utilize [`str.casefold()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) instead for case-insensitive string comparison.

Comment: Technically, case insensitive string comparison, what the Unicode specification refers to as default caseless matching requires both sides to be casefolded, i.e. X is a caseless (case insensitive) match to Y if X.casefold() == Y.casefold(). Just casefolding the input doesn't give you a case insensitive comparison